# Resize volume file length and width in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing

I have a volume file that has a variable slice length, image height of 640, and image width of 512. I want to convert it to a file with a height of 620 and a width of 420 and write it to a new file. I want to take the 20 pixels off the top of the height and take 46 off of each side of the width to do this resizing. Each pixel is unsigned 16 bits. I'm not sure how to do the actual manipulation.

This is what I have in my main:

```
FILE* pfile = NULL;
FILE* pfile2 = NULL;

pFile = fopen("test.vol", "rb");
fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);

int fileData = ftell(pFile);
rewind(pFile);

char* FileBuffer = new char[fileData];
fread(FileBuffer, fileData, 1, pFile);

int height = 640;
int width = 512;
int slizeSize = height * width * 2;
int sliceCount = fileData / sliceSize;
uint16_t pixels;

int newHeight = height - 20;
int newWidth = width - 92;
int newSliceSize = newHeight * newWidth * 2;
int newImageSize = newSliceSize * sliceCount;

char* NewFileBuffer = new char[newImageSize];

for (int i = 0; i < newHeight; i++) {

    for (int i = 0; i < newWidth; i++) {

    }
   // need help in these for loops and after

}

fclose (pFile);
free (FileBuffer);

pFile2 = fopen("test2.vol", "wb");
fwrite(NewFileBuffer, NewImageSize, 1, pFile2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're programming in C++, use C++: get rid of `FILE*`and other C stuff.

You're allocating an array of `char` with `new`, but call `free` to release memory: you should call `delete[]`, or even better you should use `std::vector` and let it manage memory for you.

You're dealing with 16 bits values, so why not reading/writing/processing 16 bits values?

First, read the file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using data_type = uint16_t;

    std::basic_ifstream<data_type> file_in{
        "test.vol",
        std::ifstream::binary
    };
    std::vector<data_type> FileBuffer{
        std::istreambuf_iterator<data_type>(file_in), 
        std::istreambuf_iterator<data_type>() // end of stream iterator
    };
```

Now `FileBuffer` is an array of `uint16_t` filled with the content of `"test.vol"`, with managed memory allocation and deallocation.

Next part, resize the volume. I assume your data are packed in the following order: columns, lines, slices. It is unclear if the top are the first, or the last lines of a slice. Here is my proposition using iterators and `std::copy`:

```
    size_t height = 640, width = 512;
    size_t sliceSize = height * width;
    size_t sliceCount = FileBuffer.size() / sliceSize;

    size_t newHeight = height - 20, newWidth = width - 92;
    size_t newSliceSize = newHeight * newWidth;
    size_t newImageSize = newSliceSize * sliceCount;

    std::vector<data_type> NewFileBuffer(newImageSize);

    auto it_buffer = FileBuffer.begin();
    auto it_new_buffer = NewFileBuffer.begin();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sliceCount; ++i)
    {
        // skip 20 first lines, remove and uncomment the next line
        // if you want to skip the last ones
        auto it_line = it_buffer + 20*width;
        //auto it_line = it_buffer;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < newHeight; ++j)
        {
            auto it_column = it_line + 46;

            it_new_buffer = std::copy(
                it_column,
                it_column + newWidth,
                it_new_buffer
            );

            it_line += width; // go to next line
        }

        it_buffer += sliceSize; // go to next slice
    }
```

Finally, write the file:

```
    std::basic_ofstream<data_type> file_out{
        "test2.vol",
        std::ofstream::binary
    };
    std::copy(
        NewFileBuffer.begin(),
        NewFileBuffer.end(),
        std::ostreambuf_iterator<data_type>(file_out)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but im getting a ton of errors when I compile this.  error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘data_type’ seems to have caused a chain reaction of errors

Comment: I tried compling in c++ 11 and 98 and still got the errors

Comment: Okay i fixed that bug. Now I'm getting "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'
  what():  std::bad_cast
Aborted (core dumped)"

Comment: The code is indeed c++11. How did you fix the errors? Which call is throwing?

Comment: I changed `using data_type uint16_t;` to `using data_type = uint16_t;.` I tried using gdb to debug the program but its not giving me a clue as to where its having issues

Comment: Based off of print statements i made, it has something to do with this part `std::basic_ifstream<data_type> file_in{
        "test.vol",
        std::ifstream::binary
    };
    std::vector<data_type> FileBuffer{
        std::istreambuf_iterator<data_type>(file_in), 
        std::istreambuf_iterator<data_type>() // end of stream iterator
    };`

Comment: any ideas? im stuck here